# What version of Ruby 2.0.0 is the stable version?

Tags: ruby, version, ruby-2.0

I wanted to install Ruby 2.0.0 through rbenv for a project, because they list their Ruby version as 2.0.0. But there are a couple different versions listed there:

```
2.0.0-dev
2.0.0-preview1
2.0.0-preview2
2.0.0-rc1
2.0.0-rc2
2.0.0-p0
2.0.0-p195
2.0.0-p247
2.0.0-p353
2.0.0-p451
2.0.0-p481
2.0.0-p576
2.0.0-p594
2.0.0-p598
```

I guess 2.0.0-p598 is the most stable one, but what is the meaning of the following suffixes and what state of development do they represent?

- dev
- preview
- rc (this is release candidate, I know this one)
- pXXX

And can I use any of these for a Ruby project that uses `Ruby 2.0.0`?

Comment: https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/tree/master/share/ruby-build

Comment: This is just the same list, isn't it? I can't see any other information there.

Comment: The [official Ruby website](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) says that 2.0.0-p643 is the most current release version.

Comment: @cremno, thanks! But why are there stable versions of Ruby like `2.1.0`, `2.1.1`, `2.1.2` etc. but no `2.0.0`. What exactly is the `p` suffix?

Comment: @hattenn: Because the [versioning](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/12/21/ruby-version-policy-changes-with-2-1-0/) was changed starting with 2.1.0. The `p` mean patch (level). It's explained on the linked site (even though it's not important anymore for most users).

Comment: @cremno, that explains it, thank you. If you can add your comment as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`2.0.0-dev` is the [`ruby_2_0_0`](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/branches/ruby_2_0_0/)  SVN branch. The development (mostly merging fixed issues from [`trunk`](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/)) of future 2.0.0 releases is done there.

`2.0.0-previewX` are preview releases that may contain some serious issues or features that'll never be a part of the first stable release (`2.0.0-p0`). For example, `2.1.0-preview1` had frozen string literals (`'frozen'f`) which were later replaced by an optimized `String#freeze`.

`2.0.0-rcX` is a [release candidate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#Release_candidate). In the best case just bugs get fixed before the release, but in the (recent) past Ruby core developers did more like introducing [an annoying warning](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10661).

`2.0.0-pX` are stable releases of 2.0.0. `p` means patch (level) and is followed by the number of commits since the first 2.0.0 stable release. Starting with 2.1.0 the [version policy](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/12/21/ruby-version-policy-changes-with-2-1-0/) was changed and this number isn't much of interest to end users anymore.

To find out which is the most current version of the 2.0.0 series, you can visit the [official downloads site](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/).